# Angular6 - value of response header from one http request to another one as option without nested subscribes

Tags: header, rxjs, httprequest, httpclient, angular6

I need to retrieve all specified records from an api endpoint using http get request. The information what is the of total records available is in the X-Total response header. 
I tried to retrieve the value of X-Total response header with one http request and then passing the value to another http get request as the value of X-Size header - this approach resulted in nested subscribe:

```
 getTotalRecords () {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/loans/marketplace?', {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'X-Size': '1'
          }),
          params: new HttpParams().set('rating__eq', 'A').set('fields', 'rating,amount'),
          observe: 'response'
         })
        };

  getData() {
    this.getTotalRecords().subscribe(data => {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/loans/marketplace?', {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'X-Size': data.headers.get('X-Total')
          }),
          params: new HttpParams().set('rating__eq', 'A').set('fields', 'rating,amount'),
          observe: 'response'
        }).subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data.body);
      })
  })
};
```

This works but it seems to me like there has to be a better way of doing this. Also I have this code directly in a component because I wasn't able to make a service out of it - I don't know how to return an observable if I have to subscribe to one to create the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` to invoke the inner Observable and then `share` before returning the Observable to make sure you won't make multiple HTTP calls when making multiple subscriptions:

```
getData() {
  return this.getTotalRecords().pipe(
    concatMap(data => this.http.get(...)),
    share(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I needed.